# Deploy a terraform template to azure using ansible

Tags: azure, ansible, terraform

I have a terraform template which is to deploy a single vm in azure but I don't know how to deploy it using ansible.

Firstly  I tried deploying it with terraform only but not ansible.

How can  do it with ansible?
I don't have much knowledge of ansible.

Thank you.

Comment: have you looked at the examples on the terraform module for ansible https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/terraform_module.html#examples

Comment: yes. but confused how to :(

Comment: Is there a reason you want or have to use ansible rather than just using terraform itself?

Comment: I'm learning ansible and all the things I search on the internet confuses me. I wanted to use ansible to deploy the template and see the difference myself.

Comment: Well, not really a lot of reasons to do that. I don't know how would you see the differences if you were to use Ansible to deploy terraform.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I am not a fan of using ansible to deploy terraform. As your question doesn't give any real concrete example below is a terraform and ansible file that run together.

```
terraform {

}

provider "random" {}

resource "random_pet" "name" {}

output "pet_name" {
  value = random_pet.name.id
}
```

```yaml
---
- name: Running terraform
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    project_dir: ./
  tasks:
    - name: Basic deploy of a service
      community.general.terraform:
        project_path: '{{ project_dir }}'
        state: present
        force_init: true
      register: tf_result

    - name: tf outputs
      debug:
        var: tf_result.outputs
```

**OUTPUT**

```bash
ansible@cf7cc0c4226a:/local$ ansible-playbook main.yml 
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [Running terraform] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Saturday 29 October 2022  15:23:48 +0100 (0:00:00.018)       0:00:00.018 ******
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Basic deploy of a service] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
Saturday 29 October 2022  15:23:49 +0100 (0:00:01.052)       0:00:01.070 ******
changed: [localhost]

TASK [tf outputs] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Saturday 29 October 2022  15:23:58 +0100 (0:00:08.812)       0:00:09.882 ******
ok: [localhost] => {
    "tf_result.outputs": {
        "pet_name": {
            "sensitive": false,
            "type": "string",
            "value": "growing-opossum"
        }
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Saturday 29 October 2022  15:23:58 +0100 (0:00:00.050)       0:00:09.932 ******
===============================================================================
community.general.terraform --------------------------------------------- 8.81s
gather_facts ------------------------------------------------------------ 1.05s
debug ------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.05s
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
total ------------------------------------------------------------------- 9.91s
```

Comment: thanks for this.   I actually have a template which I call as main.tf and yml. See below:              `---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  collections:
    - community.general.terraform
  tasks:
    - name: Execute Terraform Template from previous activity
      terraform:
        project_path: ?
        state: present
        force_init: true`

Comment: I'm confused on how to execute this. Should I just run the yml file after the terraform template?
?
Is the project_path the directory of my terraform file(main.tf) in my local machine?

Comment: Yes. but its still makes no real sense to be running it like this. but sure you can just run the ansible playbook with the project path as the dir where your terraform files are

Comment: I got and error when  just run it

Comment: [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match
'all
PLAY [localhost] *
TASK [Gathering Facts] *ok: [localhost]

TASK [Execute Terraform Template from previous activity] ***fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to find required executable \"terraform\" in paths: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program 

PLAY RECAP *localhost               : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0